# Image Stitching: not generating result

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, image-stitching

**I have run this code. It seems to be that result.png is not generated as a result:**

```
public class ImageStitching {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MatVector images = new MatVector();
    images.put(0, cvLoadImage("image1.jpg"));
    images.put(1, cvLoadImage("image2.jpg"));

    IplImage result = new IplImage();
    int status = stitcher.stitch(images, result);

    if (status == stitcher.OK) {
      cvSaveImage("result.jpg", result);
    }

    result = (IplImage) cvLoadImage("result.jpg");

    final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame();

    // Request closing of the application when the image window is closed.
    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Show image on window.
    canvas.showImage(result);

  }

  private static void cvSaveImage(String string, IplImage result) {
  }

  private static Object cvLoadImage(String string) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**It doesn't show an error message, but it doesn't show the result either.**

Comment: Please try again with the sample code here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv/samples

Comment: Dear friend Samuel, thank you for your comment. Tried to run this code you are jealous of. However, it displays the following error:

Module 'pytorch' production: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


This is for the program to run.

Comment: That code doesn't use PyTorch, you're probably not looking at the right place.

Comment: I downloaded all of it right from Github. After that, I put it to run and when running this error message appears.